# AutoLGB tuning 'list index out of range'

Tags: python, performance, parameters, index-error, automl

```
X = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([x for _, x in p_dict.items()]))
X_tst = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([x for _, x in p_tst_dict.items()]))

p = np.zeros((X.shape[0], n_class), dtype=float)
p_tst = np.zeros((X_tst.shape[0], n_class), dtype=float)
for i_cv, (i_trn, i_val) in enumerate(cv.split(X, y)):
#    if i_cv == 0:
        clf = AutoLGB(objective='multiclass', metric='multi_logloss', params={'num_class': n_class}, 
                      feature_selection=False, n_est=10000)
        clf.tune(X.iloc[i_trn], y[i_trn])
        n_best = clf.n_best
        features = clf.features
        params = clf.params
        print(f'best iteration: {n_best}')
        print(f'selected features ({len(features)}): {features}')        
        pprint(params)
        clf.fit(X.iloc[i_trn], y[i_trn])
#    else:
        train_data = lgb.Dataset(X[features].iloc[i_trn], label=y[i_trn])
        clf = lgb.train(params, train_data, n_best, verbose_eval=100)
    
    p[i_val] = clf.predict(X[features].iloc[i_val])
    p_tst += clf.predict(X_tst[features]) / n_fold
```

I use '#' because I want to use the best params for all folds not using fold 1's params for rest folds
but I got errors

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-ae6bce31bf8f> in <module>()
      9         clf = AutoLGB(objective='multiclass', metric='multi_logloss', params={'num_class': n_class}, 
     10                       feature_selection=False, n_est=10000)
---> 11         clf.tune(X.iloc[i_trn], y[i_trn])
     12         n_best = clf.n_best
     13         features = clf.features

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/hyperopt/pyll/base.py in toposort(expr)
    713         G.add_edges_from([(n_in, node) for n_in in node.inputs()])
    714     order = list(nx.topological_sort(G))
--> 715     assert order[-1] == expr
    716     return order
    717 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I fix it?
How can I use the best params for all folds?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Kaggler and fixed in 0.9.15 ([PR](https://github.com/jeongyoonlee/Kaggler/pull/71)). Please update Kaggler using

```
pip install -U kaggler
```